# Can I set a Salesforce Chatter user as account owner?

Tags: chatter

Is it possible to assign Chatter user as owner to Salesforce Account?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it isn't possible. Chatter Free and Chatter Plus users cannot be account owners. Here's a list of things that Chatter Plus users can do: http://na8.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_chatterplus_tipsheet.pdf (PDF)

Comment: Broken Link. Try http://www.salesforce.com/chatter/editions-pricing.jsp

Answer (score 2):

They can't be owners, but they can be referenced in a non-owner User Lookup field

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just tested this in my org. I created a lookup to User on an Account, but I can't view my Chatter Only users in the list.

Comment: That's strange. I had it in my prior org. Maybe it's just Chatter + users?

Comment: Could be possible with Chatter +. I don't have any licenses to test that with.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have Chatter Plus users in our User lookups without doing anything special.  I wish there was a list of things you CANNOT do with Chatter licenses.  For example, I think we just stunmbled across that a CPlus user cannot create List Views.